# Robot framework script exit in test case failed and not contueing

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am new in robotframework and I requirement is to read file which contained lots of test data which needs to be tested sequentially and generate LOG and REPORT for each test data passed or failure.

I have prepared a script which is able to read and executing the test data sequentially but my problem is I am reading and executing test data from single test case so once it is failed execution stopped exit and report showing one test case executed and it is failed where as I have run multiple test data.
"Run Keyword And Ignore Error" skipping all error so I am unable to know which test data failed.

Could you please help me to prepare a script in robotframework which will solve the above problem?

Thanks in advance.

Anirban

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below keyword. It will continue execution, even if it failed.

`Run keyword And Continue On Failure`